# How to change icon app only in application manager android?

Tags: android, icons, android-launcher

Is it possible to change the icon of my android application only in the applications manager **(Settings->manage applications)** to be something other than the app icon (Launcher)?
I use **android:icon** in the **AndroidManifest** but it changes the twice. I honestly can't find any answer to this.

Comment: May i know why you wan to do that?

Comment: i need it because i want the default icon's color white but it can be refused by play store community so i want to keep it white in the default icon and blue in the application manager.

Answer (score 2):

By Settings->manage applications, if you mean Device Setting Account manager icon, then in your application res folder you can find xml folder, from the xml file on that folder you need to change your icon. 
For example --

```
<account-authenticator 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="@string/auth_type"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_contest_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_contest_icon" />
```

you need to put your icon id from drawable on `android:icon="@drawable/ic_contest_icon"`
and `android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_contest_icon"`

Comment: it works only in account manager but i want it in manage applications. Is there any way to do that ?